# LayeredBar Chart using JFreeChart Scale with minimum labels

Tags: java, charts, scale, jfreechart, bar-chart

I am trying to plot a graph, Where I want Y axis with Major Labels and Minor scales with out label of the range.

```
NumberAxis yAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
yAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(1));
yAxis.setAutoRange(true);
yAxis.setAutoRangeMinimumSize(height);
```

using above code I'm getting a plot with all Labels overlapping.
But I required a chart as below where chart has scale same as ruler has i.e. Major scale with label and minor scale without label

Please help?

Comment: You need to attach the example chart that shows what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JFreeChart does have support for minor tick marks:

```
NumberAxis yAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
yAxis.setMinorTickMarksVisible(true);
plot.setRangeMinorGridlinesVisible(true);
```

If you want to change the number of minor tick marks, then you have to create a custom TickUnitSource if you want to retain the auto-tick-unit-selection feature.